# How does multi threading solutions in nodeJS (like thread, Gogo ) work?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I am intrigued by the way the various threading solutions like webworkers, threads, thread gogo npm modules work ?

Reason for this query is due to my understanding that if I have a single core CPU , my event loop is going to hogg the CPU for processing the incoming requests. On top of this , if I create 5 worker thread, a total of 6 node js processes is going to be started but all of these processes is going to fight for the single CPU time? Is that even possible?

Comment: Multiple processes on a single core will be time sliced by the OS.  Each will run a short bit of time, then control will switch to another process for a short bit of time and so on with each process that actually has something to do with the CPU getting successive tiny slivers of CPU.  Processes that are only waiting on a mutex or something like that will not get any CPU time until they need it as they have nothing to do.  Note that running more simultaneous and active processes than the number of cores you have will slow things down, not speed things up.

Comment: So if I have just a single node JS instance without any thread, so even my node js event loop will be getting CPU time based on time slicing as I will have other processes running on my desktop which will need CPU time?

Comment: Yes, the OS will attempt to share the CPU among all active processes.

Comment: FYI, node uses only one thread for the main JS event loop, but may also use some other threads in the implementation of some asynchronous operations such as node.js file services.

Comment: So with the threading solutions provided by various npm modules, does each of the thread creates its own event loop and callback queue?

Comment: If you want to know how a specific node.js module works, you'll have to ask about a specific node.js module.  They likely aren't all implemented the same way.